# Is it possible to prove the content of an encrypted message without disclosing the private key?

Tags: encryption

Suppose that I sent Bob a message saying, "The meeting is cancelled", and encrypted it with his public key.

Could he share the plaintext with other people, without disclosing his private key (and therefore compromising the secrecy of the other messages)?

I found [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72902/how-to-prove-bob-has-received-alice-message) discussion, but I don't think it's a duplicate, or even relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming there is no randomness added to the message during encryption (or that Bob reveals that randomness) then anyone who encrypts the plain-text message with Bob's public key will get the same cipher-text that Bob received / published. That is, of course, assuming that Bob can prove the cipher-text is genuine.